# which kill is called? bash builtin or /bin/kill

Tags: linux, bash, unix

when i type

```
kill -s ‹n› ‹pid›
```

in terminal, is it calling bash builtin or /bin/kill?

for this question, assume it's Ubuntu default setup (bash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ LANG=C type kill
kill is a shell builtin
```

Comment: If using csh/tcsh:  `which kill`  (just for completeness -- I know the question specifies bash)

Comment: I force `LANG=C` because I am a French Frog, and I prevent anyone here to read some strange language with `diactitics`, like `Molière` wrote (years ago) and such wicked guys.

Comment: ...Mhhh, `LANG` VARIABLE is a system VARIABLE that means : set the `locale` as a stupid (drunk on friday night) French `STUFF`. DEFAULT is C, that means English language...

Comment: if `$ type kill; kill est une primitive du shell` is more relevant, I can upgrade my poor POST. So what ?! =)